# Investigating interior, closure and boundary of the set

Tags: real-analysis

> $E = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$ find the interior, closure and the boundary of the set.

The Solution Manual says that interior point of $E$ is $E$. More rigorously,

$E^{\mathrm{o}}=E$ which also means that E is open. But I don't understand the reason. Why $E^{\mathrm{o}}=E$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I presume $n$ and $k$ were supposed to be the same letter? Anyways, what two or three equivalent definitions of "open set" ore you familiar with, and which ones did you test here?

Comment: Sorry I will edit it.

Comment: 1. If $E^{\mathrm{o}}=E$, then E is open. 2. If $E^{\mathrm{c}}$ is closed, then E is open. 3. A subset $\mathrm{V}$ of $R^{\mathrm{n}}$ is said to be open iff for $\forall a \in \mathrm{V}, \exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(a) \subseteq \mathrm{V}$

Comment: To me, that's a theorem, not a definition.

Comment: I edited it. I didn't handle to write in latex fast

Comment: If you can do (2), then you can try (2). Otherwise do (3). Unwind recursively all the definitions until you reach a quantitative statement. Then evaluate the resulting quantitative statement.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in E$. Then there is an $n$ such that $a \in \bigl( \frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n} \bigr)$. Let
$$
\varepsilon := \min\biggl\{ \Bigl\lvert a - \frac{1}{n+1} \Bigr\rvert, \Bigl\lvert a - \frac{1}{n} \Bigr\rvert \biggr\}.
$$
Then $B_\varepsilon(a) \subset \bigl( \frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n} \bigr)$, so $B_\varepsilon(a) \subset E$. Thus, $a$ is an interior point of $E$, which shows that $E$ is open since $a$ was arbitrary.